# Jquery Window scroll .... if else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I face some issues in window scroll function in `if...else`

It only go in through  `SCROLL END 1`.

Anyone can tell me where I'm doing wrong or suggest me to make it better. Thanks a lot

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollend = 1250;
        var second_scrollend = 4500;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= scrollend) {
            console.log("SCROLL END 1");
            $("#sidepanel").css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'bottom': '10px', 'width': '300px' });
        } else if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= second_scrollend) {
            console.log("SCROLL END 2");
            $("#sidepanel").css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'bottom': marginbottom + 'px', 'width': '300px' });
        } else {
            $("#sidepanel").css({ 'position': 'relative', 'bottom': '0px', 'width': 'auto' });
        }

    });
```

Comment: what's exactly your requirement? Could you please explain.

Answer (score 0):

change your variable value

```
 var scrollend = 4500;
 var second_scrollend = 1250;
```

Why we change the  value

Your first codition always true because `if $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() is greater than 1250` it is always true

> Other Way change the sequence of condition

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= second_scrollend) {
            console.log("SCROLL END 2");
            $("#sidepanel").css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'bottom': marginbottom + 'px', 'width': '300px' });
        }
else if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= scrollend) {
            console.log("SCROLL END 1");
            $("#sidepanel").css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'bottom': '10px', 'width': '300px' });
        }
 else {
            $("#sidepanel").css({ 'position': 'relative', 'bottom': '0px', 'width': 'auto' });
        }
```